# Different colours on one line in batch?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I found this code which changes the colour of the text in Batch:

`powershell write-host -fore Red -back Yellow "Hello World!"`

But can I have different colours on the same line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
write-host -fore Red -back Yellow "Hello World!" -NoNewline
write-host -fore Cyan -back Green " Merry Christmas!"
```